# Fiware Orion: Geolocation Filters for Subscriptions

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I am aware that you can `queryContext` Orion using geolocation filters.

Is it possible to do a similar filtering in a subscription scenario? In other words, could I be notified of changes on the attributes of a context entity, **only** when the possition attribute is inside a predefined area?

For instance:
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NGSI protocol takes into account the possibility of specifying restrictions on subscriptions. So the subscribeContext operation supports the FIWARE::Location restriction on subscriptions.

So the answer is: yes.

### Example

Create an entity with POST queryContext:

```
{
  "contextElements": [
  {
    "type": "City",
    "isPattern": "false",
    "id": "Madrid",
    "attributes": [
    {
      "name": "position",
      "type": "coords",
      "value": "1, 1",
      "metadatas": [
      {
        "name": "location",
        "type": "string",
        "value": "WGS84"
      }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "a1",
      "type": "string",
      "value": "v1"
    }
    ]
  }
  ],
  "updateAction": "APPEND"
}
```

Subscribe to changes in an area with POST subscribeContext:

```
{
  "entities": [
      {
          "type": "City",
          "isPattern": "true",
          "id": ".*"
      }
  ],
  "attributes": [
      "a1"
  ],
  "reference": "http://<host>:<port>/notify",
  "duration": "P1M",
  "notifyConditions": [
      {
          "type": "ONCHANGE",
          "condValues": [
              "a1"
          ]
      }
  ],
   "restriction": {
      "scopes": [
      {
        "type" : "FIWARE::Location",
        "value" : {
          "polygon": {
            "vertices": [
            {
              "latitude": "0",
              "longitude": "0"
            },
            {
              "latitude": "0",
              "longitude": "6"
            },
            {
              "latitude": "6",
              "longitude": "6"
            },
            {
              "latitude": "6",
              "longitude": "0"
            }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
      ]
    }
}
```

And then just update the value of *a1* of the entity and see what happens.